# Truncating text to the next line using CSS

Tags: css

I have a box which looks like this with in the image [image: current image]

I want to truncate the text so that the next words can be visible in the next line. Something like this:
[image: target image]

I am using:

```
width: 230px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

But with ellipsis its coming to be ABCD DESB EAR E...
Is there any way of bringing it to the next line?

The following is the html:

```
<tbody role="ppt"><tr role="ppt"><td class="dijitButton" role="presentation"><div class="dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="textDirNode" role="ppt"><span role="opt" aria-selected="true" class="dijitValidationTxtBxLbl " style="width: 230px;text-overflow: ellipsis;
">Walmart.com/Jet.com Price</span></div><div class="dijitContainer"></tbody>
```

```css
.dijitValidationTxtBxLbl {
  width: 230px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody role="ppt">
  <tr role="ppt">
    <td class="dijitButton" role="presentation">
      <div class="dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="textDirNode" role="ppt"><span role="opt" aria-selected="true" class="dijitValidationTxtBxLbl">Walmart.com/Jet.com Price</span></div>
      <div class="dijitContainer"></div>
      </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the `html` too ?

Comment: Added @johannchopin

Comment: You don't need `text-overflow: ellipsis;` a `span` is an inline element, if you want it to respect your `width` property you need to give it `display: block` or something similar to make into a block element. Even better, don't use a `span`

Comment: I put your code into a snippet and had to close the td, tr, and table. Please feel free to update it to look more like the issue in your screenshots.

Comment: @volt I cant modify the html. Its only the css Also i added display:block, nothing happended

Comment: A note: the word ellipsis refers to `...`, so the text overflow option `ellipsis` is explicitly telling the browser to use the ... method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `word-wrap: break-word;` for `dijitValidationTxtBxLbl` class :

```
.dijitValidationTxtBxLbl {
  width: 230px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```